# How to download my android app to my computer so I can fix it in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

It's my app that I never published to the Google Play Store and then foolishly deleted the source code. So there is no way to download it from a site and no copyright infringement.

The app is on an old phone I have and I'd like to be able to fix it up in Android Studio and put it on my new phone.

I've been looking everywhere on Google and on this site but I can't find the right combination of search terms.

Comment: You can have any apk extractor on your phone, I use shareit or esfileexplorer to create a apk backup and then copy that apk from phone to desktop. If you have not used any obsfucator in your app then you will be able to reverse engg and extract the code.

Comment: Did you edit the source in Android Studio before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try using Xender or Shareit to get the APK
2. Try using some tools to decompile it like Android Apk decompiler

   http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk/